# product.Category: (models.E015) 'ordering' refers to the nonexistent field, related field, or lookup 'name'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am following a tutorial on YT and I can't migrate my models.

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255),
    slug = models.SlugField(),

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/{self.slug}/"
```

I've tried several potential solutions...

[typo issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65118618/errors-blog-post-models-e015-ordering-refers-to-the-nonexistent-field-rel)

```
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-name',)
```

tuple & typo?

```
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-name')
```

[tuple issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273633/error-models-e015-ordering-refers-to-the-nonexistent-field-related-field)

```
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name')
```

...but to no avail.

I would love if someone could help me out with this

Comment: why do you have a comma at the end of your lines when defining your model fields? Remove it.

Comment: remove the trailing commas after the field definitions, that is the tuple issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there're extra comma at the end of your model fields (name and slug). Try to remove them

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/{self.slug}/"
```